# Error : Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $coreRegistry

Tags: magento-2.1, error, controllers

I have a controller in my custom module, but when i run **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**, i got this following error:

> Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $coreRegistry

here's my controller code:

```
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    protected $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
    ) {
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you extentd the class **\Magento\Backend\App\Action** which is inherited from **\Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction**. Here if you see the constructor,only one parameter takes. But you passed two parameter. Thats why you getting this error. You can try the following code:

```
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

protected $_dataPersistor;
protected $_coreRegistry;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry= $coreRegistry;
    $this->_dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
    parent::__construct($context);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Prasanta hatui its working for me