# Compile: Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $context

Tags: magento2, module, controllers, dependency-injection, class

This has been asked a few times I know and I studied all of them and I also get the ieda what went wrong. However I cannot adapt those solutions to my issue.

I have a Class **Post** which extends **\Magento\Backend\App\Action**:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml;

abstract class Post extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action { ...
```

And I have a class **Save** that extends this **\Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Post**:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

class Save extends \Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Post { ...
```

Class **Post** has the following `__construct()`:

```
public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Model\PostFactory $postFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
    )
    {
        $this->_postFactory           = $postFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry          = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

Class **Save** has the following `__construct()`:

```
public function __construct(
    \Vendor\Module\Model\Upload $uploadModel,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\Post\File $fileModel,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\Post\Image $imageModel,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\PostFactory $postFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
)
{
    $this->_uploadModel    = $uploadModel;
    $this->_fileModel      = $fileModel;
    $this->_imageModel     = $imageModel;
    $this->_backendSession = $context->getSession();
    parent::__construct($postFactory, $registry, $context);
}
```

As far as I understand, the Post Class takes 3 Parameters in construct and I provide 3 Parameters to parent construct in Save Class. However when I execute `setup:di:compile`, I get the following error:

```
Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save
        Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $context. File: /html/magento2/app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Save.php
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this? I have been trying for hours, but I can't get rid of it...

The following is one of the threads I found, but like I said I can't adapt this on my own:
[Error : Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $coreRegistry](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157352/error-extra-parameters-passed-to-parent-construct-coreregistry)

**NOTE:** Of course I created the needed protected variables accordingly, so there is no issue here.

Comment: Any chance you have something older in your generated folder?

Comment: No, I already checked it 100 times... I am totally frustrated ...

Comment: odd. It should not matter but what if you put the context first in the method declaration in both your Post and Save classes.

Comment: Well I tried it, but now I have a blank page and when compiling I get: Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save
  Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context. Actual type: \Vendor\Module\Model\PostFactory; File: 
/html/magento2/app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Save.php

Comment: did you also change the order of the parameters in the `parent::__construct($postFactory, $registry, $context);` call?

Comment: Yes I did, I am just not getting what is going wrong here ...

Comment: did you fixed this?